# Crash in [NSWindow orderFrontRegardless] after updating to macOS Mojave

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, crash, macos-mojave

Getting this weird crash after updating to Mojave.

Not doing anything special, just creating an NSWindow and calling   `orderFrontRegardless`

Always worked fine before.

```
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff6610ab5d _sigtramp + 29
2   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39b00bb6 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39b00b30 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39b00a9a _CFXRegistrationPost + 404
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39b08f48 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 87
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39a71994 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1642
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39a70d47 _CFXNotificationPost + 732
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff3bdab217 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff3720538b -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:stashSize:] + 3090
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff37204766 -[NSWindow _setFrame:display:allowImplicitAnimation:stashSize:] + 192
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff3720469f -[NSWindow setFrame:display:] + 51
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff3727aca9 -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindowAboveOrBelow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1336
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff372792a0 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 283
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff37a0dce9 -[NSWindow orderFrontRegardless] + 40
```

Code (it's a console app):

```
NSWindow *window =    [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect
styleMask:windowStyle
backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
defer:NO];

// Since Snow Leopard, programs without application bundles and Info.plist
// files don't get a menubar and can't be brought to the front unless the
// presentation option is changed
[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];

 [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
 [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Comment: Possibly a notification being sent to a released/dead object. Have you got a minimum code sample?

Comment: @WarrenBurton I've added the code.

Comment: Is the comment relevant? i.e Is this app without plist and bundle? . I can't reproduce the crash in a regular baseline "Cocoa App" template.

Comment: Yes, it's a console app.

Comment: That last stack frame of `_sigtramp` suggests you have a signal handler installed - possibly a 3rd party crash reporter. Where did this stack trace actually come from? Those often do mess with Apple's ReportCrash making it impossible to capture the original crashing stack trace.

Comment: @Mattie I use sigaction() and backtrace_symbols_fd(). I posted an answer, it was a memory bug completely unrelated to this stack trace. Do you know a better way to get valid stack traces?

Comment: You cannot use `backtrace_symbols_fd` safely from a signal handler. Check out `man sigaction` for some details. I'll follow up with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated that you were dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. But, I don't have enough information from the report you posted to know if this was (perhaps by luck) null, or just garbage memory. I'll assume that at some point you crashed with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (signal equivalent is `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV`, depending).

The **critical** bit of information here was that you had a signal handler installed.

Signal handlers generally (but not always) run on the crashing thread using the same stack. The kernel injects the handler using that `_sigtramp` function. Upon signal delivery, current stack state contained the information you needed to track down the bad memory access. But, your signal handler was invoked instead. So it ran, mutating the stack as it did.

Then, your signal handler completed somehow. It is possible to configure a signal handler using `sigaction` such that the process state is restored to the moment just before the crashing event. I'm not sure how your signal handler was configured. But, ultimately, I'm going to assume that the process was allowed to exit.

At this point, Apple's ReportCrash would have been triggered, and would capture backtraces for all threads **in whatever state your signal handler left them**. This is critical, because that's not necessarily the crashing state.

Adding complexity, `backtrace_symbols_fd` is **not at all safe** to use from a signal handler. Async safety is challenging, and running code from a signal handler is **highly** difficult to get right. There are very few things you can do safely. I'm pretty sure, additionally, that `backtrace_symbols_fd` allocates memory. So, if your crash was in the memory allocator somewhere, and it sounds like it was, you were definitely at risk for a deadlock. Judging by the backtrace, it seems like that's exactly what might have happened. Check out `man sigaction` for some details.

Worse, unwinding the stack over a signal handler frame is particularly challenging because of the magic the kernel does to run your handler. That's why that `???` frame is in there.

A summary:

Without a signal handler installed, Apple's ReportCrash would have produced a correct (and likely helpful) backtrace for the crashing thread.

The stack trace you've included isn't great, but it's hard to know exactly why.
It appears that `backtrace_symbols_fd` didn't do a good job of unwinding, possibly due to it being inappropriate to use from a signal handler, possibly because it isn't backed by a good-enough stack unwinding mechanism for this situation. But, without more information, it's difficult for me to know. I am surprised the the top frame was `_sigtramp`, though. That doesn't make a lot of sense. It makes me think something might have been going wrong in the signal handler itself. It **is** possible to crash a second time in your handler.

Apple's backtraces (generated by ReportCrash, `backtrace_symbols_fd`, or NSThread's `callStackReturnAddresses`, for example) can definitely be trusted, provided you're careful to use them in safe contexts.

Comment: This is super useful. Thanks a lot for spending the time. It was an uninitialized pointer pointing to garbage, since I had a != NULL check, and it didn't help. I'm developing this app in my own language that compiles to C, and I've added automatic pointer initialization for every single field to prevent this from happening again :)

Comment: I'll avoid calling `backtrace_symbols_fd` from the sig handler from now on.

Comment: You are very welcome! Project sounds cool, and I understand whyyou

Comment: You are very welcome! Project sounds cool, and I understand why you'd want this. It is possible to do stack unwinding in a signal handler, it's just a lot more manual work - particularly on macOS.

Answer (score 4):

How do you initialize the app? Do you have `NSApplication` initialized before using `AppKit`?

Something like these steps should be necessary in main.m:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSApplication* application = NSApplication.sharedApplication;

    AppDelegate* delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    application.delegate = delegate;

    [application run];
}
```

Also your delegate might be getting deallocated, since `NSApp` holds a weak reference to it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the @autorelease pool, still get crashes for 10% of users. I think there's a memory bug somewhere deep, will debug it with Valgrind on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a serious memory bug in a completely different place not even mentioned in the backtrace.

I was dereferencing an uninitialised pointer.

This is the second time it happens.

**Do no trust Apple's backtraces when debugging memory errors.**

Even with libgmalloc.

Comment: I posted an answer that I hope is useful. I would bet that if you reproduced this crash without your signal handler, you'd find the backtraces you get either from a debugger or ReportCrash (Apple's automatic crash reporting mechanism) to be much more helpful.